# Clicks on Google adsense as a goal in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using **Google Tag Manager** and would like to create an event based on clicks on Adsense ads. And then create a goal in Google Analytics based on this event.
What is the best and simple way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  I suggest you try googling your problem make an attempt at it and come back if you have any problems we would be happy to help.

Comment: I googled the problem and found this page, which told me to google the problem.  I am stuck in an infinite loop.